# Jquery conflict: jquery.min.js vs rollover images script

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-social-plugins, rollover

I have a website with the images as the menu buttons. I use rollover function for them to be highlited on mouseover. Everything worked fine until I needed to insert facebook social plugin, that uses jquery.min.js. This leaded to a conflict - either the rollover function works or facebook plugin works - I've tried to put the jquery.min.js line in every possible way inside the html file, but hve the same result. I guess I have a problem with the variables and need to use jQuery.noConflict(); but not sure how as every way I've tried it - failed. The code is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
  <script type="text/javascript">

     var i, x, a=document.MM_sr; 
     for(i=0; a && i < a.length && (x=a[i]) && x.oSrc; i++) {
        x.src = x.oSrc;
     }

     function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
       var d = document; 
       if(d.images){ 
          if(!d.MM_p) 
             d.MM_p=new Array();
       var i,j = d.MM_p.length, a = MM_preloadImages.arguments; 
       for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
         if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0){ 
            d.MM_p[j]=new Image; 
            d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];
         }}
     }

     function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
       var p, i, x;  
       if(!d) 
         d = document; 
       if((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
         d = parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; 
         n = n.substring(0,p);
       }
       if(!(x = d[n]) && d.all) 
         x = d.all[n]; 
       for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++) 
         x = d.forms[i][n];
       for(i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++)
         x = MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
       if(!x && d.getElementById) 
         x = d.getElementById(n); 
       return x;
     }

     function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
       var i, j = 0, x, a = MM_swapImage.arguments; 
       document.MM_sr = new Array; 
       for( i= 0; i < (a.length - 2); i += 3)
         if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i])) != null){
           document.MM_sr[j++] = x; 
           if(!x.oSrc) 
             x.oSrc = x.src; 
           x.src = a[i+2];
         }
     }

 </script>
</head>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting specifically?

Comment: Dreamweaver shows syntax error warning in a line after  <script type="text/javascript">. As for the work of a website - images just don't rollover.